# AsyncCall with Delphi 2007

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, delphi-2007

What I basically want is to start [AsyncCall](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) and  proceed with my code loading. I have Interface section that consumes lots of time (600+ms) and I want to load this code in independent thread.

I've tried to use `AsyncCall` to make something like this:

```
procedure Load;
begin
...
end;

initialization
  AsyncCall(@Load, []); // or LocalAsyncCall(@Load)
```

However, this `Load` procedure actually starts in Main thread and not in the new created thread. How can I force the `Load` procedure to be loaded in any thread other than `MainThread`?

I can create `TThread` and `Execute` this but I want to force `AsyncCall` or `LocalAsyncCall` or anything from `AsyncCall` library to make to work.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't working. Even if I put it out of initialization but Load procedure on some dummy button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your code is not retaining the `IAsyncCall` interface that is returned by the `AsyncCall` function.

```
AsyncCall(@Load, []);
//AsyncCall returns an IAsyncCall interface,
//but this code does not take a reference to it
```

Because of this, the interface that is returned has its reference count decremented to zero as soon as the initialization section completes. This therefore frees the object that implements the interface which does this:

```
destructor TAsyncCall.Destroy;
begin
  if FCall <> nil then
  begin
    try
-->   FCall.Sync; // throw raised exceptions here
    finally
      FCall.Free;
    end;
  end;
  inherited Destroy;
end;
```

The key line is the call to `Sync` which forces the asynchronous call to be executed to completion. All this happens in the main thread which explains the behaviour that you report.

---

The solution is that you simply need to keep the `IAsyncCall` interface alive by storing it in a variable.

```
var
  a: IAsyncCall;

initialization
  a := AsyncCall(@Load, []);
```

In the real code you need to ensure that `Load` had completed before running any code that is reliant on `Load`. When your program reached a point where it required `Load` to have been called it has to call `Sync` on the `IAsyncCall` interface.

So you might write it something like this.

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

procedure EnsureLoaded;

implementation

uses
  AsyncCalls;

....

procedure Load;
begin
  ....
end;

var
  LoadAsyncCall: IAsyncCall;

procedure EnsureLoaded;
begin
  LoadAsyncCall := nil;//this will effect a call to Sync
end;

initialization
  LoadAsyncCall := AsyncCall(@Load, []);

end.
```

The call `EnsureLoaded` from other units that required `Load` to have run. Or, alternatively, call `EnsureLoaded` from any methods exported by `MyUnit` that depended on `Load` having run. The latter option has much better encapsulation.

Comment: I've tried this and you're right. But try to make brakepoint on that conditional line and you'll see that clicking on both button1 or button2 you'll receive the same thread IDs - it enter in MyProc from the same thread.

And when I do that in my main code (not test app) I see that Load procedure is performed in main thread, not in someother thread.

Also I can't put any sleep into Initialization section cause that part should work maximum fast. But even when I put it it's the same.. :(

Comment: @Ivan Clearly I'm not suggesting that `Sleep` is the answer. `Sleep` is never the answer to any question! I was just trying to explain what's going on and give you some clues. Anyway, I'm pretty much sure that kobik has pointed you to the solution.

Comment: Of course, thanks for the help and effort. Unfortunately what ever I do I receive the same results and code is ALWAYS performed in the MainThread. I afraid that Delphi version is bad and that AnsycCall lib works good with 2009 and higher. Tomorrow in office I will try with the latest Delphi version and will eliminate this possibility.
If not, then I'm going to create myown thread.

Comment: @Ivan Andreas who wrote this code is a superstar. I'm sure it works in D2007 is he says it does. He says it works on D5 even. If you could post a minimal sample that does not work I'm sure we can find a resolution. But yes, a separate TThread would be easy enough too!

Comment: http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/25420

I've just download this new code. I think that problem was in the version I had. Now it's working good. Thanks for the help (!!)

Comment: @Ivan No idea where you got your version from and why you are looking on Code Central. The latest and greatest is here: http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/  and is even linked from your question (and my answer)!!

Comment: You got me interested in this unit enough to learn a bit more. I can now see that my original answer was completely bogus. But since you accepted it I cannot delete it. So I made the re-wrote the answer to make it at least correct!!

Comment: @Ivan: "Very strange library AsyncCalls!" What's strange about it? You ask AsyncCall to sync, and it does. If the background thread wasn't started yet, it simply executes the function in the thread that called Sync. There is no need to wait for the background thread to start and than wait for it to finish. You can force this behavior with the ForceDifferentThread method, but it isn't the default.  And you are using the old API (because you are using Delphi 2007). The new API uses generics and doesn't depend on assembler code and calling convention hacks and works in 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: @Andreas Is my answer even remotely accurate? I confess to never having looked at AsyncCalls until this question. I was pleased to have had the prompt to do so. It looks fantastically versatile.

Comment: @Serg I reverted your edit. It was bogus as Andreas explains. Since you asked it to Sync there's hardly any point getting another thread to do the work since you are going to wait for that thread to complete.

Comment: @David Your answer is correct. He would need the global IAsyncCall interface to not synchronize immediately if the scope of the interface vanishes. It is very important to never call the AsyncCalls functions without storing the interface away. Worst case is a loop where the compiler had to generate 1 temporary interface variable. The loop would execute the calls sequentially because there is only 1 interface that gets reassigned on every iteration.

Comment: @AndreasHausladen Strange that GUI thread can be used by default to perform background task. I guess GUI application is not a primary target of AsyncCalls.

Comment: I just forgot a new feature of AsyncCall: IAsyncCall.Forget. This method allows you to keep the tasks alive without storing the IAsyncCall reference. But you can't control or synchronize with those tasks anymore.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for that. It's hard to imagine why you would not hold on to the interface. How else would you be able to call sync and be sure that the code had completed?

Comment: @Serg It's because you called Sync and therefore have stated, I am going to block this thread. In that case there's no point starting the task on a different thread. Don't call Sync and it won't run on the GUI thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, I am beginning to understand AsyncCalls logic. But it is VERY unexpected that background task can be performed in GUI thread.

Comment: @Serg: The GUI-Thread is used because Sync is called in it. So it has to wait and block. When I wrote AsyncCalls (for myself) I needed to communicate with a slow PHP WebService when the user pressed a button. And instead of creating a TThread, I wanted a simple way to wait in the button's OnClick handler for the thread to finish (that's why the LocalAsyncExec and TAsyncCalls.MsgExec functions exist). AsyncCalls wasn't intended to be a full-fledged threading library like [OmniThreadLibrary](http://otl.17slon.com).

Comment: @David The Forget function was a request from some AsyncCalls users. So what should I do other than implement it :-)

Comment: @AndreasHausladen Very noble of you. Not sure I would have done so in your position. But now I know that if I want something added to that library (or indeed your other ones), I just have to ask!  ;-)  How does it work? Presumably your code remembers the interface and cleans up anything outstanding at unit finalization.

Comment: @Andreas: I've miss in documentation that I should declare IAsyncCall interface as global. That is why I had problems.
When I run my main app in several initialization units I start loading in independent threads. In the main thread, before form show, I put while not LoadAsyncVal.Finished and ... do Application.ProcessMessages (wait). But sometimes (I performed stresstests) that IAsyncCall is not set back to finished even if it completed op. It's a hard for me to reproduce this cause it happens randomly; that is why I had to put some Timeout.Anyway Im using it now and I will read more your doc

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried something like this?:

```
procedure Load;
begin
  if GetCurrentThreadId <> MainThreadID then
    Beep;
end;

var a: IAsyncCall;

initialization
  a := AsyncCall(@Load, []);
  a.ForceDifferentThread;
```

> ForceDifferentThread() tells AsyncCalls that the assigned function must
>         not be executed in the current thread.

Comment: I've tried that and it's not helping. Produce the same results - works in the main code instead in the separate thread.

Comment: @Ivan Could you show a minimal reproduction of that. When I tried ForceDifferentThread in my code it did indeed run the asynch method in a different thread.

Comment: In fact I found that just taking a reference to the `IAsyncCall` returned by `AsyncCall` is enough in my test cases to keep the code off the main thread.

Comment: I've made A var global and it's working now.

And actually it's working now WITHOUT ForceDifferentThread (!!)

Thanks for the help both to Davi and Kobik