# Why is AsyncCall running in main thread?

Tags: delphi, asynchronous, delphi-2010

I have a model object that runs long operations.  I'm trying to run some of these operations in threads to keep the interface responsive, download 2 things at once, etc, but I want to hide these details from the interface code as much as possible. I'm trying to use the AsyncCall library, but having issues.

```
type EUpdaterAction = (auFoundCurrentVersion, auFoundUpdateVersion);

type
  TUpdater = class
  public
    procedure loadCurrentVersion();
    procedure notify(action: EUpdaterAction);
  end;

procedure TUpdater.loadCurrentVersion();
begin
  TAsyncCalls.Invoke(procedure 
  begin 
    Assert(Windows.GetCurrentThreadId() <> System.MainThreadID);
    //Really long code
    TAsyncCalls.VCLSync(procedure begin notify(auFoundCurrentVersion); end);
  end);
end;
```

The assertion fails.  Do I need to do something to make it run in a separate thread, or does the first [example shown with the library](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/) just not actually run in threads?

Comment: I think we already did the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809171/asynccall-with-delphi-2007

Comment: In my case, I did just need to keep a reference to the returned interface.  That's what I get for copying code and not understanding it. :-/  Would you like to place that as an answer or should we close as duplicate?

Comment: If I were you I would upvote and accept Andreas's answer here, and upvote my answer at the other question. ;-) It's not worth me adding another answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `IAsyncCall.ForceDifferentThread` to force the code to run in a different thread. In your example the interface that TAsyncCalls.Invoke() returns is released immediately because the function ends and releasing the IAsyncCall interface calls the `Sync` method. And because your task hasn't started yet, the `Sync`method will execute it in the same thread, unless the `ForceDifferentThread` method was called.

```
TAsyncCalls.Invoke(procedure 
begin 
  Assert(Windows.GetCurrentThreadId() <> System.MainThreadID);
  //Really long code
  TAsyncCalls.VCLSync(procedure begin notify(auFoundCurrentVersion); end);
end).ForceDifferentThread; // <<<<<
```

But is that really what you want? I guess you want to keep the thread alive after loadCurrentVersion() has exited. And for this AsyncCalls isn't the right tool.

Comment: This is close, and you're right.  I did want to keep alive.  The part I actually needed was to keep the returned interface in a class variable, rather than use force different thread.

Answer (score 1):

That was already discussed on SO. When you call `Invoke` AsyncCalls puts your code into a queue to be executed; somewhat later Asyncalls will find a worker thread to execute your code, but if your code calls `Sync` **before** a worker thread was assigned to your code (and without using `ForceDifferentThread`) AsyncCalls removes your code from the queue and executes it in the main thread. That is by design.